# {{#link-to}} breaks Semantic UI

Tags: ember.js, semantic-ui, link-to

I have a template where I am displaying each event as a card and the elements of the cards either have links or not. For links to other routes, I am using the `link-to` helper but it is breaking the Semantic UI card layout. https://semantic-ui.com/views/card.html

The card perfectly fine if I remove the link-to tags. Am I missing something here or is there a better way of doing this? 
The code is as follows:

```
<div
class="ui card {{unless isWide 'event fluid' 'thirteen wide computer ten wide tablet sixteen wide mobile column'}}">
{{#unless isWide}}
  {{#link-to 'public' event.identifier}}
    <div class="ui fluid image">
      {{widgets/safe-image src=(if event.originalImageUrl event.originalImageUrl event.originalImageUrl)}}
    </div>
  {{/link-to}}
{{/unless}}
{{#link-to 'public' event.identifier}}
  <div class="ui main content">
    {{#smart-overflow class='header'}}
      {{event.name}}
    {{/smart-overflow}}
    <div class="meta">
      <span class="date">
        {{moment-format event.startsAt 'ddd, MMM DD h:mm A'}}
      </span>
    </div>
    {{#smart-overflow class='description'}}
      {{event.shortLocationName}}
    {{/smart-overflow}}
  </div>
{{/link-to}}
<div class="extra content small text">
  <span class="right floated">
    <i role="button" class="share alternate link icon" {{action shareEvent event}}></i>
  </span>
  <span>
    {{#if hasBlock}}
      {{yield}}
    {{else}}
      {{#each tags as |tag|}}
        <a>{{tag}}</a>
      {{/each}}
    {{/if}}
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: The `link-to` helper adds an `a` tag, which may break the expected element order (`div.card > a > div.content > img` instead of `div.card > div.content > img`). Therefore try to put the `link-to`'s inside the content divs (`div.card > div.content > a > img`).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used semantic-ui, but I've had what I'd guess is the same problem with default `{{link-to}}` helpers generating anchor tags where I don't want them to be.

See the "Supplying a tagName" section of the doc for `{{link-to}}` [here](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/release/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/get?anchor=link-to). The `{{link-to}}` helper inserts by default an `<a>` tag, so a snippet of your above example would look something like this post-render:

```
<a class="stuff" href="stuff" >
  <div class="ui main content">
      <!-- Smart overflow thing -->
    <div class="meta">
      <span class="date">
        01/01/0001
      </span>
    </div>
      <!-- Smart overflow thing -->
  </div>
</a>
```

Note it's all been wrapped in the anchor tags generated by the link-to helper. If that's not a layout that semantic-ui will play nicely with, you can do something like this:

```
{{#link-to 'public' tagName="li"}}
    Your other stuff here
{{/link-to}}
```

...where the tagName is whatever tag would cooperate with the semantic-ui layout.

Answer (score 1):

always remember that if you have something like :

```
{{#what-ever}}
    <whatevertag class='wrapper'>
        ... whatever inside
    </whatevertag>
{{/what-ever}}
```

you should probably simplify it to :

```
{{#what-ever tagName='whatevertag' class='wrapper'}}
    ...whatever
{{/what-ever}}
```

same thing when you create a component

```
{{!-- mycomponent.hbs --}}
<whateverTag class='my-component'>
    ...my component stuff
</whateverTag>
{{!-- EOF --}}
```

you should probably simplify it to

```
{{!-- mycomponent.hbs --}}
...my component stuff
{{!-- EOF --}}

// mycomponent.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: 'whateverTag',
    classNames: ['my-component'],
});
```

It will avoid you to have useless/unused wrapping divs and some dom/css/css-framewroks issues